# \listoftables problem: \lstinline and texcsstyle in \caption with and without caption package

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, captions

I'm using the `listings` package with verbatim code in Table `\caption` commands. When I stay away from TeX command sequences (`texcsstyle` in `listings`), all is well, as for example when I use only an `emphstyle` identifier.

When I use a `texcsstyle` TeX command sequence like `\lstinline|\newcommand|`, I first have to escape the `\` because I'm using the `\lstinline` inside the argument of `\caption`, so I use `\caption{\lstinline|\\newcommand|}`. (In the below MWE, I include the troublesome text within a `\section` command to confirm that, when properly escaped, `\newcommand` is formatted with `texcsstyle` (blue).)

But I still don't get satisfactory results. Exactly what happens depends on whether I load the `caption` package.

- Without also loading the `caption` package, no caption is displayed in the List of Tables. (The "1" for Table 1 *is* displayed, but only empty text for the caption itself on that line.)
- If I load the `caption` package, a caption is displayed. However, (a) `\newcommand` is formatted as `basicstyle` (red) rather than as `texcsstyle` (blue) and (b) `newcommand` is displayed without its prefixing `\`.

I know the following workaround: Specify optional text for the List of Tables: `\caption[optional text]{original text}` and format the optional text by hand.

I'm asking (a) can I can salvage the automatically correct behavior (that I get using `emph` identifiers) when I use `texcs` identifiers?

Further, out of curiosity,

(b) why does loading the `caption` package partially salvage what was otherwise the total fail of a blank caption line in the List of Tables?

(c) Why do I have a problem with `texcsstyle` but not the other styles (which aren't LaTeX specific)?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,%
    basicstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,%
    emphstyle=\color{green},%
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue},%
    moreemph={mykey}%
    }
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\bigskip
\section{Caption 1 text outside of caption: Emph: \lstinline|mykey|; texcs: \lstinline|\\newcommand|}
\noindent
Caption 1 text outside of caption: Emph: \lstinline|mykey|; texcs: \lstinline|\newcommand|\\
Caption 2 text outside of caption: Only Emph: \lstinline|mykey|
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{1 Emph: \lstinline|mykey|; texcs: \lstinline|\\newcommand|}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
       x  &  y\\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{2 Only Emph: \lstinline|mykey|}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
       x  &  y\\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

With the `caption` package loaded I see:
[image]

When I comment-out the `caption` package, the List of Tables looks like:
[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that seems too strong a statement w.r.t. `\lstinline` because the [`listings` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), §5.1, "Listings inside arguments," and §4.1 at #5, specifies how to escape {}\#% in order to include `\lstinline` in an argument. And indeed it works fine within `\footnote{}`, `\section{}`, and `\mbox{}`. It even works fine for `\caption` in as far as producing the caption to the table. The problem is when those captions are compiled for a List of Tables. The problem seems more-specific than that general principle.

Comment: Oh unfair ploy, quoting documentation at me:-) I guess so (I'll delete the comment)

Comment: so it's fragile command in moving argument problem,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the `.lot` file you can see the problem

```
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces 1 Emph: \lstinline |mykey|; texcs: \lstinline | newcommand|\relax }}{1}
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces 2 Only Emph: \lstinline |mykey|\relax }}{1}
```

some commands have been made safe to stop them expanding but the end result is that it is corrupted, notably the `\\` before`\newcommand`  (`\listinlines` special definition didn't take effect as it was prevented from expanding so it was written as `\lstinline` to the `lot` file.

Simplest is probably to hide the listings in custom robust commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,%
    basicstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,%
    emphstyle=\color{green},%
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue},%
    moreemph={mykey}%
    }
\begin{document}
\DeclareRobustCommand\lstA{\lstinline|\\newcommand|}
\DeclareRobustCommand\lstB{\lstinline|mykey|}
\listoftables
\bigskip
\section{Caption 1 text outside of caption: Emph: \lstinline|mykey|; texcs: \lstinline|\\newcommand|}
\noindent
Caption 1 text outside of caption: Emph: \lstinline|mykey|; texcs: \lstinline|\newcommand|\\
Caption 2 text outside of caption: Only Emph: \lstinline|mykey|
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{1 Emph: \lstB; texcs: \lstA}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
       x  &  y\\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{2 Only Emph: \lstB}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
       x  &  y\\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's awesome. It looks like you need only `\lstA` but don't need `\lstB` because `mykey` doesn't include any of the tricky characters ({}#%\). Note that you didn't substitute `\lstB` in Caption 1 and it still displayed correctly in the caption of Table 1.

Comment: @JimRatliff yes I was trying to suggest doing doing it always rather than getting lucky in some cases and avoiding doing it, as you won't always get a tex error and it's not always obvious what characters survive the lot file, so consistently avoiding the problem rather than checking every case by eye seems like a safer plan (I'll fix the lstB in caption 1:-)